# How Long Will a Device Hold Event Messages in Offline

Tags: azure-iot-edge

If my device is offline, and sending event messages that are destined for $upstream -- how long will the local $edgeHub hold on to those events?    In short, what's the max amount of time that the device can be offline before events start rotting away?

Comment: The answer solved your issue? If you have other concerns feel free let me know.

Answer (score 4):

> It is important to note that Edge hub provides at-least-once
>   guarantees, which means that messages are stored locally in case a
>   route cannot deliver the message to its sink, for example, the Edge
>   hub cannot connect to IoT Hub, or the target module is not connected.
>
> Edge hub stores the messages up to the time specified in the
>   `storeAndForwardConfiguration.timeToLiveSecs` property of the [Edge
>   hub desired properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-edgeagent-edgehub#edgehub-desired-properties).

You can set this property in portal like this:

[image]

[image]